# | ,^, <<= , >>= Mathematical Operations in python

Tags: python, math, operators

I have tried to find out about these operations in Python:

```
x|3
x^3
x>>=3
x<<=3
```

I couldn't find anything. Please can anyone tell me what are these operations are called, so that I can search more about them.

Comment: bitwise or, bitwise xor, in-place right shift, in-place left shift. Reference [Bitwise operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: Please ignore the answers that were posted to this question before it was closed. They are awfully wrong. `^` is ***not*** "to the power of", and `>>=` is ***not*** "greater than".

Comment: `>>=` and `<<=` are not in-place since integers are immutable in Python.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Python has methods known as "magic" or "dunder" (i.e. double-under) methods like `__add__()` that define what happens when operators like `+` are used.